# SQL Relationship Query

Tags: sql

I have a database for bus ticketing system. It will have many buses. Buses would have their seats. Would one table for buses and one for seats work? OR do I have to make different tables for every bus? Explain how I could solve it.

Comment: One table for buses and one for seats seems proper. DON'T make a separate table for each bus. That would be a bad idea. You want your data to grow in number of records, not in tables/columns.

Comment: As long as your seats table has a foreign key linking your buses table you will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

A common structure for this type of data would be to have two tables: one for the buses and one for the seats. All the seats for all the buses would be in the "seats" table, and each seat would have a busID field to link back to the buses.
Your seat table might have the following columns:

```
BusID,SeatID,Seat_Info
```

The seat table would be tied to the Bus table with a foreign key, so if you ever change or delete a bus ID, all the seats would go with it. You might want to look into [How to use foreign keys](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of your tables or what data will be served how, but here's what I think it will look like. Your Bus table will probably have a list of Busses and will sort of serve as a reference table for your SEATING table.

```
tblBus
BusID  BusName  BusStartRout BusEndRoute <-- example of columns in your table
7      BlueBus  NY            LA
8      RedBus   SF            NY
```

and then you will have your SEATING table

```
tblSeating
SeatID  BusID     SeatName 
1       7         Whatever
2       8         Whoatever
```

`SeatID` -will in this table should be your Primary Key, and could be set up to be an autoIncrement in which case every time you enter a new record, it would take the last entered SeatID and auto increment it by 1.

`BusID` - will be a foreign key - You will use BusID to reference the tblBUS in order to know the BusName or whatever.

Just to give you a general idea.